# About the Feature selection in timestamped from industrial process

Tags: feature-selection

We are working with timestamp data from an industrial process, so I want to make a linear model for target value based on some measured values.

There is a high probability that the lagged values of features contribute to the model.

There are some redundant and some irrelevant features in the dataset. I want to do feature selection. So, These are my question :

1. I want to remove the redundant features using correlation matrix
   values. What is a good threshold for
   kipping/removing features? For example, 0.95 or 0.995? Is there any
   good reference?
2. What is the best method for detecting relevant/irrelevant features
   in timestamped data?

The data is not a classical time series. However, there are exogenous inputs.

Comment: Instead of thresholding correlation values you could try to use Sparse Principal Component Analysis using Lasso, Elastic Net or a similar robust sparse loss function. This will likely give you better features, although you need to figure out how to make it work on time series data.

Comment: Please do not over-use bold, which has the opposite result than desired (i.e. makes your post harder to read - edited).